# Should I be worried about FFT being off by a factor of 6

Tags: python, audio, fft

Everything seems to be working fine when I am trying to turn a wav file into a dataset (csv file) When I attempt to FFT it, it seems to work fine with the exception of it being off by a factor of 6, is this something I ought to worry about?

Furthermore another question I have is regarding a wav file, so I found the data inside and got ints out of them. They are 2 byte signed shorts, so I am aware that they have limits of  -32767-32767 and are the amplitude. However I am confused on how do these convert into actual volume?

Code

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
import sys
import struct
import csv

# all files and stuffs need to contain their tags ('potatos.wav')

def wavToData(wavName):
    stream = wave.open(wavName)

    num_channels = stream.getnchannels()
    sample_rate = stream.getframerate()
    sample_width = stream.getsampwidth()
    num_frames = stream.getnframes()

    raw_data = stream.readframes( num_frames ) # Returns byte data
    stream.close()

    total_samples = num_frames * num_channels
    if sample_width == 1: 
        fmt = "%iB" % total_samples # read unsigned chars
    elif sample_width == 2:
        fmt = "%ih" % total_samples # read signed 2 byte shorts
    else:
        raise ValueError("Only supports 8 and 16 bit audio formats.")

    total_samples = num_frames * num_channels

    integer_data = struct.unpack(fmt, raw_data) # this is amplitude
    return integer_data, num_frames, sample_rate 

def dataToWav(wavName,data):
    # IMPORTANT hard coded standard values, refenced from the audiocheck.net files
    stream = wave.open(wavName,"wb")
    stream.setnchannels(1)
    stream.setframerate(44100)
    stream.setsampwidth(2)
    numFrames = len(data)
    stream.setnframes(numFrames)
    fmt = "%ih" % numFrames 

    data = struct.pack(fmt,*data) #unpacks all
    stream.writeframes(data)


def wavToCsv(wavName,csvName): 
    with open(csvName, 'wb') as csvfile: #contain all data in 1 row
                                                # x = time (1 frame)
                                                # y = freq
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        #get data
        integer_data, num_frames, sample_rate = wavToData(wavName)
        #adds headings and other needed data
        frameCount = [x+1 for x in range(num_frames)] # x
        fullData = [x for x in integer_data] # y
        frameCount.insert(0, "Time (increments of %f)"%(1/sample_rate))
        fullData.insert(0,"Frequency(dBfs)")
        fullData = frameCount+fullData
        filewriter.writerow(fullData)

def mergeWavData(wav1,wav2,mergeWav): #generates a brand new wav file
    firstData = wavToData(wav1)[0]
    secondData = wavToData(wav2)[0]

    limitCheck = lambda x,y: ((x+y)> 32767 or (x+y) < -32767)
    limitConstrain = lambda x,y: 32767 if (x+y) >32767 else -32767
    newData = []

    if len(firstData) < len(secondData): #adds the amplitudes of both wav file up to the shortest one
        for i in range(len(firstData)):
            data = 0
            if(limitCheck(firstData[i],secondData[i])): #exceed limit
               data = limitConstrain(firstData[i],secondData[i])
            else:
               data = firstData[i]+secondData[i]

            newData.append(data)

    else:
        for i in range(len(secondData)):
            data = 0
            if(limitCheck(firstData[i],secondData[i])): #exceed limit
               data = limitConstrain(firstData[i],secondData[i])

            else:
               data = firstData[i]+secondData[i]

               if (data > 32767 or data <-32767):
                 print data
            newData.append(data)


    dataToWav(mergeWav,newData)

mergeWavData('audiocheck.net_sin_1000Hz_-3dBFS_3s.wav','audiocheck.net_sin_4000Hz_-3dBFS_3s.wav','1000Hz+4000Hz.wav')
wavToCsv('1000Hz+4000Hz.wav','1000Hz+4000Hz.csv') # maeks csv out of wav ayayayay
#include tags (.wav/.csv)
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
import sys
import struct
import csv

# all files and stuffs need to contain their tags ('potatos.wav')

def wavToData(wavName):
    stream = wave.open(wavName)

    num_channels = stream.getnchannels()
    sample_rate = stream.getframerate()
    sample_width = stream.getsampwidth()
    num_frames = stream.getnframes()

    raw_data = stream.readframes( num_frames ) # Returns byte data
    stream.close()

    total_samples = num_frames * num_channels
    if sample_width == 1: 
        fmt = "%iB" % total_samples # read unsigned chars
    elif sample_width == 2:
        fmt = "%ih" % total_samples # read signed 2 byte shorts
    else:
        raise ValueError("Only supports 8 and 16 bit audio formats.")

    total_samples = num_frames * num_channels

    integer_data = struct.unpack(fmt, raw_data) # this is amplitude
    return integer_data, num_frames, sample_rate 

def dataToWav(wavName,data):
    # IMPORTANT hard coded standard values, refenced from the audiocheck.net files
    stream = wave.open(wavName,"wb")
    stream.setnchannels(1)
    stream.setframerate(44100)
    stream.setsampwidth(2)
    numFrames = len(data)
    stream.setnframes(numFrames)
    fmt = "%ih" % numFrames 

    data = struct.pack(fmt,*data) #unpacks all
    stream.writeframes(data)


def wavToCsv(wavName,csvName): 
    with open(csvName, 'wb') as csvfile: #contain all data in 1 row
                                                # x = time (1 frame)
                                                # y = freq
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        #get data
        integer_data, num_frames, sample_rate = wavToData(wavName)
        #adds headings and other needed data
        frameCount = [x+1 for x in range(num_frames)] # x
        fullData = [x for x in integer_data] # y
        frameCount.insert(0, "Time (increments of %f)"%(1/sample_rate))
        fullData.insert(0,"Frequency(dBfs)")
        fullData = frameCount+fullData
        filewriter.writerow(fullData)

def mergeWavData(wav1,wav2,mergeWav): #generates a brand new wav file
    firstData = wavToData(wav1)[0]
    secondData = wavToData(wav2)[0]

    limitCheck = lambda x,y: ((x+y)> 32767 or (x+y) < -32767)
    limitConstrain = lambda x,y: 32767 if (x+y) >32767 else -32767
    newData = []

    if len(firstData) < len(secondData): #adds the amplitudes of both wav file up to the shortest one
        for i in range(len(firstData)):
            data = 0
            if(limitCheck(firstData[i],secondData[i])): #exceed limit
               data = limitConstrain(firstData[i],secondData[i])
            else:
               data = firstData[i]+secondData[i]

            newData.append(data)

    else:
        for i in range(len(secondData)):
            data = 0
            if(limitCheck(firstData[i],secondData[i])): #exceed limit
               data = limitConstrain(firstData[i],secondData[i])

            else:
               data = firstData[i]+secondData[i]

               if (data > 32767 or data <-32767):
                 print data
            newData.append(data)


    dataToWav(mergeWav,newData)

mergeWavData('audiocheck.net_sin_1000Hz_-3dBFS_3s.wav','audiocheck.net_sin_4000Hz_-3dBFS_3s.wav','1000Hz+4000Hz.wav')
wavToCsv('1000Hz+4000Hz.wav','1000Hz+4000Hz.csv') # maeks csv out of wav ayayayay
#include tags (.wav/.csv)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The amplitude is converted to a voltage by your DAC and then "sent" to your speakers. The amplitude of that is your perceived volume. Your short values can represent `2**16` values (16 bit), so with an ideal DAC and speakers you can get about 96dB of dynamic range.

Comment: read up on PCM which is the fundamental way audio to processed digitally ... essentially those integers represent points on the audio curve as it wobbles about ... think of a plot where left to right is time and up down is the audio amplitude ... greater number of bits available to store each integer point on that audio curve gives you greater fidelity ... consider this if each point on audio curve was stored in one bit it could only have two values so your curve would get recreated looking like a zig zag however even one byte (8 bits) gives you 256 distinct possible integers so smoother curve